# SVG image on Hover

Tags: image, svg

I have an SVG image for A project that I am working on. Now I want to change the color on hover. I have the middle working on Hover. my issue is how can I also Hover the outline line.

```
<svg width="108" height="108" viewBox="0 0 108 108" fill="#ffffff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="54" cy="54" r="53" stroke="#1B1D27" stroke-width="2"/><path id="hover-style-svg"d="M30 60L54.1228 48L78.5 60" stroke="#1B1D27" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>
```

Comment: There's no hover code in your question so how do you a) have the middle working on hover? and b) What outline line is supposed to change color on hover?

Comment: please provide more code and details about platform, language, device, etc you need this to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet and see if this is what you are looking for since the question is too vague.

```css
svg:hover * {
  fill: black;
  stroke: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="108" height="108" viewBox="0 0 108 108" fill="#ffffff" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="alert('You have clicked on svg')">
      <circle cx="54" cy="54" r="53" stroke="#1B1D27" stroke-width="2" />
      <path id="hover-style-svg" d="M30 60L54.1228 48L78.5 60" stroke="#1B1D27" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
```